# ctypes pointer of unsigned integer 64 bit in python

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I am sticking in converting a list to `ctypes.c_uint64`. here is my code:

```
num_c = ctypes.c_uint32(num)
arrLen = ctypes.c_uint32(length)
zeroInt64 = ctypes.c_uint64(0)
zeroList = [zeroInt64] * length 
uint64_array_c = ctypes.c_uint64(zeroList)
```

but it gives me back this error:

> TypeError: an integer is required

Would you please let me know where is the problem?

and I would like to know what would be the pointer of this array in ctypes?
I mean `ctypes.POINTER` of this array.

Comment: `zeroList` is a list, not an integer

Comment: Do you want to convert _each entry_ in the list to `c_uint64`?

Comment: well, as I mentioned I want to convert a list to ``uint64``

Comment: You can try `uint64_array_c = [ctypes.c_uint64(zeroInt64)] * length` or list comprehension `uint64_array_c = [ctypes.c_uint64(i) for i in zeroList]`

Comment: @ForceBru if it would easy to convert for sure it is my aim.

Comment: ... you **cannot** convert a list into **any** kind of int(broad brushes... but mostly true)... you could convert all the values in the list to a datatype....

Comment: @kuro would you please let me know the pointer of this list?

Comment: Do you  want a `c_uint64` array with `length` elements that's all zeros? That's simply `uint64_array_c = (ctypes.c_uint64 * length)()`. As to a pointer, what for? If it's for passing as a function argument, don't bother. Arrays degenerate as pointers to the first element in function calls.